# Allegro 5, flickering sprite C++

Tags: c++, allegro

I'm new to allegro 5. I'm currently writing a simple 2D game in C++. 
I used to use Allegro 4 but there was no major support for .PNG images so I changed it. The problem is that in Allegro 4 I could easily create a double buffer for my sprites so they do not flicker nor blink while moving. In allegro 5 there is just "al_draw_bitmap" function which does not let us give any buffer for an argument. 
This part of my code looks like this:

```
 al_draw_bitmap(image[0],poz_x,poz_y,0);
 al_draw_bitmap(platf, 0, 400, 0);
 al_draw_bitmap(p1, poz_p1x, poz_p1y, 0);
 al_draw_bitmap(chmurka, 50, 50, 0);
 al_flip_display();
 al_clear_to_color(al_map_rgb(0,0,0));
```

I can't find any solution on the internet.
I would be really pleased if you could help me.

Comment: Can you draw everything to one bitmap, and then draw that bitmap on the screen?

Comment: al_flip_display() works internally with double buffers, you don't need to specify it. Why do you clear your display after flipping? Try clearing it to black before drawing anything and let flip() be the last call in your render method.

Comment: Is there any other place where you're flipping the display? Is this all your drawing code?

Comment: Alegro 5 use OpenGL or Direct X for drawing, so out of the box it is double buffered unless you as using single buffered flags  https://liballeg.org/a5docs/trunk/display.html#al_flip_display